# How to detect broken CSS background images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to detect broken CSS background images with Javascript and/or jQuery? For example, I would like to iterate over a div and find any elements that have background images which are not working such as:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item" style="background-image: url("image1.jpg");"></div>
  <div class="item" style="background-image: url("image2.jpg");"></div>
  <div class="item" style="background-image: url("image3.jpg");"></div>
</div>
```

We can't use a function to load the images as traditional HTML image elements to check the headers due to CORS limitations, so we need to be able to check the content that has already been loaded on the page.

How can I detect broken CSS background images with JavaScript?

Comment: You can't. CSS can only **apply** styles not detect them.

Comment: The proposed solution at that link attempts to load the images via Ajax to test if they are valid or not. As noted in the original question we have a CORS limitation which would prevent this from being a viable solution.

Comment: You can create an image element for each and use the built in error event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a quick'n'dirty solution for looping through items and then matching the URL in `img.src` and added **error** listener to detect whether the src could be found.

Here's an example: https://codepen.io/zvona/pen/XWRQEzr?editors=1111

The JS code looks like this:

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

items.forEach((item) => {
  const imageURL = window.getComputedStyle(item).getPropertyValue('background-image');
  const rgURL = /url\(['|"](.+)['|"]\)/gi;
  const imgSrc = (rgURL).exec(imageURL)[1];
  const img = document.createElement('img');

  img.setAttribute('src', imgSrc);  
  img.addEventListener('error', ({ target }) => {
    console.warn(`${target.src} is not found`);
    item.style.borderColor = 'red';
  })
});
```

Comment: What if the background is set by class?

Comment: True. I need to use `getComputedStyle`. Will fix this one

Comment: Very nice solution - this works!

Comment: Don't forget multiple background images - just a bit more fiddly but your method would work.