# How to detect background-image loading for each page lazyload element to prevent broken images

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, background

I'm trying over my computer to make a lazyloader for images that dynamically replaces the css value `background-image` with the attribute `data-bgimg`

The code for doing this it's very simple.
See below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.lazyloadbg').each(function(i, e) {
if ($(e).attr('data-bgimg')) {
    $(e).css({ "background-image": "url('" + $(e).attr('data-bgimg') + "')"    });
}
});
});
```

So when there is an element with the class `lazyloadbg` like this

```
<div class="lazyloadbg" data-bgimg="/something.jpg">
</div>
```

the background image it's replaced dinamically after the page code loading.

---

Now the question.

For big images (as you can see from this image linked) the image becomes corrupted and I got an error called "`NS_ERROR_NET_PARTIAL_TRANSFER`".

[NS_ERROR_NET_PARTIAL_TRANSFER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJZ18.png)

***The image extrabig was made ad hoc for testing*** (it's over 50MB).

Now, how to detect if the image it's corrupted?

I tryied something like

```
    document.addEventListener('error', e => {
        if (e.target.matches('img')) {
        console.log(e.type, e.target, e);
        } else if (e.target.matches('script'))  {
            //do nothing
        } else if (e.target.matches('style'))  {
            //do nothing
        } else if (e.target.matches('link'))  {
            //do nothing
        } else if (e.target.matches('iframe'))  {
            //do nothing
        } else {
            console.log(e.type, e.target, e);
        }
    }, true);
    
    document.addEventListener('load', e => {
        if (e.target.matches('img')) {
        console.log(e.type, e.target, e);
        } else if (e.target.matches('script'))  {
            //do nothing
        } else if (e.target.matches('style'))  {
            //do nothing
        } else if (e.target.matches('link'))  {
            //do nothing
        } else if (e.target.matches('iframe'))  {
            //do nothing
        } else {
            console.log(e.type, e.target, e);
        }
    }, true);
```

but the error and also the loading are not detected as event (I'm talking about the background-image change in style).

***So how to solve this?***

P.S. I even tried it too like in this answer [How to detect broken CSS background images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68792591/how-to-detect-broken-css-background-images)

```
    const items = document.querySelectorAll('.lazyloadbg');

    items.forEach((item) => {
      const imageURL = window.getComputedStyle(item).getPropertyValue('background-image');
      const rgURL = /url\(['|"](.+)['|"]\)/gi;
      const imgSrc = (rgURL).exec(imageURL)[1];
      const img = document.createElement('img');

      img.setAttribute('src', imgSrc);  
      img.addEventListener('error', ({ target }) => {
        console.warn(`${target.src} is not found`);
        item.style.borderColor = 'red';
      })
    });
```

but the event that should be fired it's not triggered.

Comment: Here there's a full page link if someone wants to test it. https://jsfiddle.net/zk0sem9w/ Please do not execute the fiddle over the fiddle site, but save the page over your computer (so you can see in the "NET" zone of your browser that the image has not been loaded completely). The image is a jpg with some dummy code at end which makes it bigger (49.1MB), so also you see that's loaded most of the time there's not.

Comment: If you don't get the error please add something like `?random=randomtext` after the image name, so the image it's loaded from an other location to prevent the loading from the browser cash memory

Answer (score 0):

yout can try something like this:

```
     const items = document.querySelectorAll('.lazyloadbg');

function loadImages() {
    const promises = [];
    items.forEach((image) => {
        promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            image.onload = () => resolve(image.src);
            image.onerror = () => reject();
        }));
    });
    return Promise.allSettled(promises)//return all promises, rejected or resolver
};

loadImages().then((imageUrl) => {
    //Do something when load success
})
.catch(()=>{
    //Do something when load  throws error
})
```

Comment: TNX @zGilexx I tryied also your code with the `Promise` object, but the event it's not triggered over (`//Do something when load success` `//Do something when load  throws error`). I think it's because the image it's in `style="background-image: url(...)"`

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you are trying to detect and handle errors for background images set using the background-image property via JavaScript. Unfortunately, the error and load events typically associated with the  tag are not applicable to background images set in CSS.

One approach to handle this is by preloading the images using JavaScript, and then checking for errors during the preloading process. Here's an example using your code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.lazyloadbg').each(function (i, e) {
        if ($(e).attr('data-bgimg')) {
            // Create a new Image object
            var img = new Image();
            
            // Set the source to the data-bgimg attribute
            img.src = $(e).attr('data-bgimg');
            
            // Handle the load event
            img.onload = function () {
                // Image loaded successfully, update the background-image
                $(e).css({ "background-image": "url('" + img.src + "')" });
            };
            
            // Handle the error event
            img.onerror = function () {
                // Image failed to load, handle the error here
                console.error("Failed to load image: " + img.src);
            };
        }
    });
});
```

In this example, an Image object is created for each .lazyloadbg element, and the onload and onerror events are used to handle success and failure cases, respectively. This way, you can catch errors during the preloading process and take appropriate actions.

Keep in mind that preloading images might increase the initial loading time of your page, especially if there are many large images. Consider optimizing your images or implementing a more advanced lazy-loading solution if performance is a concern.

Comment: Hi! I don't want to create an Image Object every time. "Keep in mind that preloading images might increase the initial loading time of your page, especially if there are many large images." It's for that reason that it's a lazy load that starts after the page loading process.
So I'm not searching for this. I'm searching for a solution that matches the event `NS_ERROR_NET_PARTIAL_TRANSFER` in CSS. Thanks, but at this time I'm waiting for larger browsers to implement this feature (talking about of Google Chrome, Sarari, Mozilla Firefox) 

Comment: Anyway, after I tried your code the event it's not triggered for big images :(
Please test the code before posting. Thank you!
(In the comments at the top of page it's written how to carry out the test!) 'By